# How to install Pandas and dependencies without pip or any package manager

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, numpy

My Company linux dev environment does not have pip or any package manager installed .
How can i install or use pandas package and dependencies like numpy etc without pip/package managers.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a local installation using [python wheels](https://wheel.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) on a sandbox (a directory that you will use to keep these libraries separated from your *production* stuff) and enable it by adding this path on your `PYTHONPATH`.

In practice, a [wheel](https://wheel.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is basically .ZIP file that contain python packages with the native dependencies (the object files generated from C sources, for example) already compiled for your platform (Python version, OS and CPU Architecture).

The first thing to do is to create a separate directory to keep the packages:

```
mkdir -p /full/path/to/my/pandas_sandbox
```

Go to PyPI website and download a Pandas and its dependencies:

- [Pandas](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/0.23.3/#files)
- [numpy](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/#files)
- [pytz](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/#files)
- [six](https://pypi.org/project/six/#files)
- [python-dateutil](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/#files)

You'll notice that for some of them, namely Pandas and Numpy there are a lot of options.

When choosing the packages, specially for Pandas and Numpy, you'll need to take in account the [wheel naming convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/#file-name-convention), so make sure you get the the wheels that match you python version and CPU architecture.

For example, if you need Pandas targeting Python 2.7 on Linux running on x86_64, go for `pandas-0.23.3-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl` (note the *cp27*, *manylinux1* and *x86_64*).

Identify your target platform and download the specific versions for Pandas and Numpy.

Once you have the packages (the `.whl` files), unzip them on the sandbox directory and according to my experiment using the currently valid versions, you'll end up with:

```
.
├── dateutil
├── numpy
├── numpy-1.15.0.data
├── numpy-1.15.0.dist-info
├── pandas
├── pandas-0.23.3.dist-info
├── pytz
├── pytz-2018.5.dist-info
├── six-1.11.0.dist-info
└── six.py
```

Now, add the path to your sandbox directory `PYTHONPATH`:

```
 export PYTHONPATH=/full/path/to/my/pandas_sandbox
```

This will make the packages under `/full/path/to/my/pandas_sandbox` visible for python, so you can use and import them as installed dependencies.

Example:

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=/full/path/to/my/pandas_sandbox
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
>>> pandas.__file__
'/full/path/to/my/pandas_sandbox/pandas/__init__.pyc'
>>>
```

NOTES:

1) Keep in mind this is not the recommended way to maintain your Python environments and dependencies.

2) Remember the `export PYTHONPATH=/a/given/path` as demonstrated, is only valid for the current shell session, so you can keep your python installation clean on the new shells. You can make it permanent by adding this `export` to your `.bashrc`, for example.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed solution . I will try this out and update.